# How to apply a memorize decorator to an instance method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'd like to use a memorize decorator on a class method. `cExample.pri()` calls `self.text()` but `memorize` doesn't seem to know about `self`. When `memorize` calls `self.func(*key)` it is missing the `cExample` obj so it complains about missing args.

How can I change this memorize decorator so that it is able to pass the caller's `self` to the function?

Python3.5.2

```
class memorize(dict):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self[args]

    def __missing__(self, key):
        result = self[key] = self.func(*key)
        return result

class cExample():
    @memorize
    def pri(self, text):
        return self.text(text)

    def text(self, text):
        return text

c = cExample()
print(c.pri('hi'))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(c.pri('hi'))
  File "x.py", line 7, in __call__
    return self[args]
  File "x.py", line 11, in __missing__
    result = self[key] = self.func(*key)
TypeError: pri() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Comment: The builtin `functools.lru_cache` doesn't seem to have this issue so you can consider using it

Comment: It's tricky to access cExample's `self` from inside `memorize` because the usual method binding process only works automatically for function objects, and `memorize` is a dict, not a function. You can implement method binding yourself by overriding memorize's `__get__`, but IMO doing so is complicated enough that you lose the concision that made your original idea attractive in the first place. May as well just write an ordinary function-based decorator at that point.

Comment: Do you want a single cache that handles all `cExample` instances, or do you want each instance to have its own cache? And if the former, do you want the caching to ignore `self`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `self` (i.e. `c`) to `cExample.pri` (i.e. `self.func`). But `__missing__` won't allow you to do this: it receives only the key.

You can rewrite it using function-based decorator:

```
import functools

def memorize2(f):
    cache = {}
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrapper

class cExample():
    @memorize2
    def pri(self, text):
        return self.text(text)

    def text(self, text):
        return text

c = cExample()
print(c.pri('hi'))  # hi
```

(I'm using [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) not to lose the original name of decorated method).

In this approach `self` will be passed to `wrapper` as positional arg and proxied to `cExample.pri`.